# Proyecto no me carga en visual studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Instale visual studio 2022 Enterprise en otra computadura pero al momento de abrir la solucion del proyecto que tengo, un proyecto me dice `Error al cargar`.

Intento cargar el proyecto, pero me da un error que dice.

> Un proyecto con ese nombre ya está abierto en la solución.

Cosa que no tengo abierto. Y en la consola me lanza otro error:

> \MesaDeServicios -
> Updates2\MesaDeServicios\AppMesaDeServicios\AppMesaDeServicios.csproj
> : error  : Un proyecto con ese nombre ya está abierto en la solución.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira la estructura de archivos y carpetas que están en el nivel del archivo de solución.

Answer (score 0):

Lo conseguí solucionar asi:

- Elimine el proyecto de la solución.
- reinicie visual studio.
- agregue el proyecto a la solución como un proyecto existente.

Post original [aquí](https://ajaxhispano.com/ask/por-que-dice-proyecto-con-ese-nombre-ya-abierto-en-la-solucion-104094/)